# I'm getting "nan" value for loss, while following "Question Answering with SQuAD 2.0" from the huggingface documentation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I’m following the “Fine-tuning with Custom Dataset” tutorial for Question Answering on the SQuaD dataset tutorial in the link
https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#question-answering-with-squad-2-0

when my model starts training, I don’t get the expected metric values for loss as I normally would, instead I get “nan”. Here is the code for training
`model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(16), epochs=3, batch_size=16)`

Here is the output with the "nan" values for the losses.

```
Epoch 1/3
5427/5427 [==============================] - 4604s 848ms/step - loss: nan - output_1_loss: nan - output_2_loss: nan
Epoch 2/3
365/5427 [=>…] - ETA: 1:11:28 - loss: nan - output_1_loss: nan - output_2_loss: nan
```

I don’t know what is wrong, and I don’t think this output is what is supposed to be.

Would appreciate any help in this regard.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you include how you preprocess the data?

Comment: This link has complete solution. i am unable to find. https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#question-answering-with-squad-2-0